# Error Converting Apps Script Blob from PNG to JPEG

Tags: image, image-processing, google-apps-script, blob

I'm trying to download a PNG image in Apps Script, convert it to JPEG, and generate a data URI for this new JPEG.

```js
function test() {
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/156/setup.png').getBlob();
  var jpeg = blob.getAs("image/jpeg");
  var uri = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(jpeg.getBytes());
  Logger.log(uri);
}
```

When I run this, I get:
**`The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt.`**

Even something like:

```js
function test() {
  var bytes = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://what-if.xkcd.com/imgs/a/156/setup.png').getBlob().getBytes();
  var jpeg = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, MimeType.PNG).getAs(MimeType.JPEG);
  DriveApp.createFile(jpeg);
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug on Google's side of things, so I have filed an issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69566797
Please star! ★

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. This may be a bug, but it's specific to the file you are using, so may as well be a bug in the file (i.e., the file could indeed be corrupted somehow). Or maybe it uses some features of PNG format that Google doesn't handle. Replacing the URL by another one, e.g.,

```
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/mathematica/img/logo@2.png').getBlob();
```

both functions work as expected.

Comment: I don't know whether this is useful information. In my environment, when I use a PNG file included the alpha channel, such error occurs. When a PNG file without the alpha channel, no error occurs.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to strip out transparency from a PNG in an Apps Script blob?